# Sed Fails to store the result into a variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed

I try to put the result value of this command:

```
sed "s/\$ip/${ip}/g" xdebug.conf
```

Provided from this file `xdebug.conf`:

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = $ip
xdebug.remote_port = 9091
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log
```

Into a variable named `$conmfiguration`.

In order to achieve that I try:

```
ip="125.12.22.1"
$configuration=$(sed "s/\$ip/${ip}/g" xdebug.conf)
```

But I get the following weird result:

> =zend_extension: command not found

DO you know why that happens?

Comment: Drop the `$` in front of the variable name when assigning. Running such commands / scripts with the `xtrace` option (`-x`) may help.

Comment: Php Habits usually happens whwn you develop in many languages.

Comment: I use Double quotes cause there is a variable `ip` to my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
$configuration=$(sed "s/\$ip/${ip}/g" xdebug.conf)
```

both `$configuration` and `$(sed ...)` get expanded. If the variable is empty, you get

```
=zend_extension = xdebug.so ...
```

The first word is taken as a command, and the rest as arguments to it. The shell tries to find `=zend_extension`, fails, and complains.

Remove the `$` from the left-hand side of the assignment, then the assignment works. This outputs `foo bar`:

```
var=$(echo foo bar)
echo $var
```